# b:if selection which works for both http and https

Tags: blogger

Is it possible to have a condition which covers both HTTP and https link in b:if condition selection.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == &quot;http://www.your-site.com/p/contact-us.html&quot;'>
<link href='https://xxxxxx.com/contact.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<b:else/>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.url == &quot;https://www.your-site.com/p/contact-us.html&quot;'>
    <link href='https://xxxxxx.com/contact.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
  </b:if>
</b:if>
```

This is how I got loading of this CSS working in both HTTP and https version of the website. Is there a single way to do without the ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url contains "//www.your-site.com/p/contact-us.html"'>
  <link href='https://xxxxxx.com/contact.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
</b:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `b:elseif` tag in order to check more than one condition.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == &quot;http://www.your-site.com/p/contact-us.html&quot;'>
    <link href='https://xxxxxx.com/contact.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<b:elseif cond='data:blog.url == &quot;https://www.your-site.com/p/contact-us.html&quot;'/>
    <link href='https://xxxxxx.com/contact.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
</b:if>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But is it the only way to handle both http and https in a condition?